# How to display programs, started by TSWA Remoteapp, inside a browser instead of directly on the desktop?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remoteapp, tswa

For those not familiar with Terminal Services Web Access and Resulting Internet Communication in Windows Server 2008 [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754502(WS.10).aspx)’s a brief overview.

The problem I am trying to solve can be seen in the picture of step 16 where the application is displayed directly right on the desktop [see [link](http://blogs.technet.com/askcore/archive/2008/07/22/publishing-the-hyper-v-management-interface-using-terminal-services.aspx)].

I am in the process of setting up Terminal Service Web Access RemoteApp for our company. Users only want remoteapp and need to see the remote program running within/contained-inside the browser. They don’t want to see or access the whole desktop, as the case with remote desktop, which can be displayed inside a browser.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft doesn't offer this by default I think. You will need to go to Citrix Web Interface along with Citrix XenApp.

RD Web Access, formerly Terminal Services Web Access (TS Web Access), includes Remote Desktop Web Connection, which enables users to connect remotely from a Web browser to the desktop of any computer where they have Remote Desktop acces